# Problema com relacionamento Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estou com problemas no relacionamento do meu banco, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia Cursos, ainda sou iniciante em asp.net MVC. Tenho duas tabelas **Aluno** e **Curso**, e tenho outra tabela que faz a associação entre essas duas tabelas **AlunoCurso**.

**Model Aluno**

```
 public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunoCursos { get; set; } }
```

**Model Curso**

```
public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome_Curso { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunoCursos { get; set; } }
```

**Model AlunoCurso**

```
public class AlunoCurso
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AlunoId { get; set; }

    public int CursoId { get; set; }

    public bool Aprovado { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }

}
```

O problema é que o a coluna **AlunoId** na tabela de **Curso** não está recebendo o **Id** do Aluno.
[image: Tabela Curso]

Mas na tabela de associação **AlunoCurso** está recebendo o valor do campo **AlunoId**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Lista de Cursos do Aluno**

```
public ActionResult MeusCursos()
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno != null)
            return View("MeusCursos", db.Cursos.ToList());

        return View();}
```

**View MeusCursos**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Meus Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Aluno
        </th>
        <th>
            Aprovado?
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Aprovado == false)
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-success" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id"/>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Emitir Declaração" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-default" enable="enable" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**Tela de Listagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto não é exatamente um problema. É so um rabicho de código que ficou pra trás e que não foi retirado.

Veja aqui:

```
public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome_Curso { get; set; }

    ...


    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; } // Este pode ser retirado

    public ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunoCursos { get; set; } 
}
```

Como agora um aluno pode estar matriculado em vários cursos, e um curso pode ter vários alunos, esta associação:

```
public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
```

Perdeu o sentido de estar ali, e pode ser retirada.

Após retirar, não esqueça de gerar uma nova *Migration* para a remoção da coluna adequadamente.

---

**EDIT**

A *Action* está incorreta. Se você quer ler os cursos de um aluno, basta selecionar apenas o aluno e usar as propriedades de navegação:

```
public ActionResult MeusCursos()
{
    var aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
    if (aluno != null)
        return View("MeusCursos", aluno);

    return View();
}
```

Repare que troquei `@model` da *View*:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Aluno>

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Meus Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Aprovado?
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.AlunoCursos)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Curso.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Aprovado == false)
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-success" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id"/>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Emitir Declaração" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-default" enable="enable" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Mas o que acontece @Cigano é quando eu listo os cursos que o aluno está matriculado, o nome do aluno vem sem nada, por causa desse AlunoId.

Comment: @Novato E você está listando esse nome como?

Comment: Editei a pergunta @Cigano está vindo assim em branco o campo. Quando eu colocava o número do **AlunoId** na tabela **Curso** na mão lá no banco, ele preenchia o campo **Aluno** na ´View´, mas fazendo desse jeito vinha todos os dados do aluno e não só o nome dele, entendeu?!

Comment: @Novato Editei a resposta.

Comment: Deu erro @Cigano, essa minha **Action** é do controller **Curso**. Fiz essa alteração que você indicou mas na minha **View** dá erro nessa linha também ´@foreach (var item in Model.AlunoCursos)´, ela não reconhece o **AlunoCursos**. Eu quero listar o **Curso**, **O Nome do Aluno**, e **Aprovado**.

Comment: @Novato Você está usando errado. `Curso` tem ligação com `AlunoCursos`, e `AlunoCurso` tem ligação com `Aluno`. Se você quer listar os cursos de um `Aluno`, você tem que selecionar o `Aluno` e usar as propriedades `virtual` de `Aluno`, **mesmo que seja um *Controller* de Curso**.

Comment: Então essa minha **Action** vai dentro do controller **Aluno** @Cigano ?

Comment: @Novato Seria até melhor que fosse.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar resolver de acordo com sua resposta @Cigano. Se não conseguir posso abrir outra detalhando melhor?

Comment: @Novato Sim, claro! Fique à vontade.