# Editar campo dentro de uma lista no asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um aplicação que gerencia **Cursos**, e estou tentando fazer uma listagem onde apresente na tela os **Cursos**, o **Nome do Aluno** e o campo **Aprovado**, onde indica se ele está aprovado ou não, e nessa tela eu tenho que conseguir marcar o **checkbox**. O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer sair nessa lista o do **Nome do Aluno** e nem consigo editar diretamente nessa lista o campo **Aprovado**, porque quando passo o cursor do mouse ele tá bloqueado e não posso checar, a edição desse campo nesta tela é imprescindível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha Action do Controller Curso**

```
    public ActionResult MeusCursos()
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno != null)
            return View("MeusCursos", db.Cursos.ToList());

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MeusCursos(int id)
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno != null)
            return View("MeusCursos", db.Cursos.ToList());

        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (curso == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        if (curso.Aprovado == false)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Aprovado", "Você ainda não concluiu o Curso");
            return RedirectToAction("MeusCursos");
        }

        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }
```

**Minha View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Meus Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Aluno
        </th>
        <th>
            Aprovado?
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @if (item.Aprovado == false)
                        {
                            <input type="submit" value="Pendente de Aprovação" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-default" disabled="disabled" data-id="@item.Id"/>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="@Url.Action("GerarPDF", "Aluno")"> <input type="submit" value="Emitir Declaração" name="meusCursos" class="cursos btn btn-success" enable="enable" /> </a>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".cursos").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MeusCursos/",
                    data: { id: $(this).data("id") },
                    success: function() {
                        $(this).attr("enable", "enable");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Para mais detalhes eu fiz essa pergunta aqui também [Problema com relacionamento Entity Framework](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68871/problema-com-relacionamento-entity-framework/68875?noredirect=1#comment140975_68875)

Comment: +Novato poderia escrever na pergunta o código da classe Aluno por favor? Isso nos ajudaria a entender melhor o problema do nome do aluno não estar aparecendo na listagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que o campo seja um checkbox editável, tente substituir `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)`  por `@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Aprovado)`. DisplayFor é apenas para apresentação, enquanto que EditorFor gera um campo para edição.

Quanto ao nome dos alunos não estar aparecendo, no código `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos)` você tem certeza que AlunosCursos é o nome do campo correspondente ao nome na classe Aluno? Por exemplo, se o código da sua classe Aluno é algo semelhante a

```
public class Aluno
{
    // Campo nome do aluno.
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

então você tem que substituir `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AlunoCursos)` por `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)` (perceba que eu substituí **AlunosCursos** por ***Nome***, que no caso seria o campo correto do nome na classe Aluno).

Comment: Nem precisa. Acho que é isso mesmo. Falta só o problema do nome do aluno.

Comment: Então, alterei minha resposta com mais informações. Acho que é isso também. Vamos continuar esperando uma resposta dele para confirmar. Obrigado.